# Buck converter not behaving as anticipated with new trim pot resistors

Tags: power-supply, buck, constant-current, constant-voltage

I recently purchased a 300W buck converter from amazon [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfb2g.jpg) which has two 3296W 100K trim pots to control the constant current and constant voltage output. My plan was to use them as bench power supply for which i replaced these two pots with a panel mount 100 K linear potentiometer [2]. While I undertand that the 3296W are multi-turn resistor, I was expecting I'd get the same response from the new potentiometers just in a single turn however the new pots aren't working the way they should. The output voltage is not working and I am getting fixed 22V out for 24V input irrespective of the pot adjustment.

What am I missing here ? Replacing trim pots should be basic and should'n have affected the way buck converter behaves.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfb2g.jpg) https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/B0C2YQPQXR?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

[2] https://www.amazon.com.au/Glarks-5K-100K-Knurled-Linear-Potentiometer/dp/B081GZBL8T/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=100k%2Bpotentiometer&qid=1696162452&sr=8-1-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1

[image]

Comment: `I am getting fixed 22V out for 24V input irrespective of the pot adjustment.` did you try with different input voltage?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I just tried it and the output voltage decreases linearly with decreasing input voltage. The Pot adjustment was having no effect on it.

Comment: We can't know if the connections were made properly, or if the wiring was bad, or the pot was broken. There are plenty of unchecked reasons why it might not work. Please double check what you did.

Comment: What happens if you wire the trimpots the same way - ie: via the length of wire?

Comment: @Kartman All wiring has been checked and doubled checked prior to writing this post. I suspect there's some fundamental difference betweet the mfg of two aforementioned trim pot types.

Comment: @Prashant "I suspect there's some fundamental difference betweet the mfg of two aforementioned trim pot types." Do you also consider that moving the pots some distance away from where they were on the board will have an effect on the circuit?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes. As i mentioned in reponse to Andy, I was expecting performance degradataion which would've been fine. This is just a proof of concept.

Comment: Did you check that the pcb was not damaged when you removed the trimpots? Have you ‘beeped’ out the circuit using your multimeter? You can also verify the potentiometer operation with your multimeter. You can also measure voltages. Collect evidence rather than guessing. Also, ‘not working’ is performance degradation!

Comment: Two red leads for the multimeter - an experienced person would find that dangerous, confusing and intolerable. Don’t create problems for yourself.

Comment: Are you sure the pinout is correct? Maybe the trimpots' wiper terminal isn't the one in the middle.

Comment: @Hearth absolutely. I've got datasheet for both and both of them have wipers in the middle pin 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What am I missing here ? Replacing trim pots should be basic and
> should'n have affected the way buck converter behaves.*

It could affect it so much that the device goes unstable and burns. On the other hand, you might get a quite unstable output or, if you are really lucky it might work. But, the chances are that something unpredictable will happen.

The trimmer pots are connected to the most sensitive part of the circuit and any extra capacitance (wiring to ground or a bulky panel mount potentiometer) will likely make the output unstable. Plus there's the inductance of the extra wiring to throw into the mix.

<sub>Pretty much all devices bought from Amazon (and several others) have no data sheet and haven't been designed with any thought about you making modifications to them. They also have quite a debatable manufacturing provenance and, designs are likely to change without you being informed. In short, don't use them for things like this or expect them to perform beyond their fairly limited specifications.</sub>

Comment: This is just a proof of concept and while I was expecting performance degradation of these super cheap buck converters, I wasn't prepared for complete failure of the experiment from a mere pot replacement. I will try shorter leads and see how it goes.

Comment: @Prashant If shorter leads don't work, you could make a mechanical linkage to the pots on the board, or a flexible shaft in a Bowden tube. But that might be more work than reasonable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton As you mentioned, the issue with with the sensitivity of pcb mount trim pot compared to the panel mount potentiometer. While I smoked one of the buck converter, these second one seems to respond well when I mount the module straight on a PCB with another trim pot. This is exactly the response I was looking for.